# 16.04 Headphones detected but not working properly

Tags: 16.04, sound, headphones

Tried using alsamixer to no avail. However I noticed when I used "test sound" in "sound settings", I am able to hear a short spark in the correct side of the headphones during the start and end of the audio que. How should I proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

I had a similar effekt (hearing a short spark) when i first tried headphones (16.04 notebook here). I had to change Soundsettings -> Play sound through -> Headphones Built-in Audio, and change the Output volume to a pretty high level.

I have however no experience with alsamixer, if this was your concern.

In the end i used a audioplayer (vlc) and a song i knew, as a reference, to avoid having to go Test sound, as changing the Outputvolume did not regulary produce a signal.